# aws ec2 instance suddenly not reachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an ec2 linux server with a spring boot application and nginx reverse proxy. It has been running for months.
Today I tried accessing the server and it was not reachable, nor via ssh, nor via http.
I went to cloudWatch and saw these metrics : [image]

I don't know how to interpret this : EBSReadBytes raised to 8 GB for an hour.

To gain access to the server I had to restart the instance. After that I went to nginx access logs :

[image]

Last java logs :
[image]

I don't see anything unusual in nginx logs. (The censored lines are from legit users)
For the java app, I usually have these kind of logs on my development computer when I let it go to sleep and comeback, but never had these on my linux server.

Do you have an idea why this happened ?

Answer (score 1):

I am now pretty sure it was a resource leak due to not closing a file input stream.